# How to convert a huge single line json file to a multi line file without opening it?

Tags: json, bash, ubuntu

I have a large (around 200Mb) single-line json file and I want to convert this to a more readable multi-line json (or txt) file.

I tried to open the file with text editors like sublime text and it takes forever to open. So, I would like to make the conversion without opening the file.

Therefore, I cannot use the interface suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003470/how-do-i-convert-a-single-line-json-file-into-a-human-readable-multi-line-file) SO question.

I tried to `pretty-print` the json file as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301431/8889727) answer by doing the following.

```
cat myjsonfile.json | python -m json.tool > pretty.json
```

But the terminal prints the following message and I get an empty `pretty.json` file.

```
Extra data: line 1 column 34255 - line 1 column 173769197 (char 34254 - 173769196)
```

I'm thinking of installing visual basic, just to convert the file. But is there a better and efficient way to do the conversion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest method would be using `jq` to pretty print the json:

```
jq . myjsonfile.json > pretty.json
```

But from the python output, I suspect the json file may be ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. `jq . myjsonfile.json > pretty.json`. Now I can even open the multi-line file in sublime text!

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you can use [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) unix utility to pretty-print your one-liner json:

```
jtc myjsonfile.json
```

you can use there `-t` option to control indentation.
If you like *to convert* `myjsonfile.json` from one-liner into pretty-printed, then use option `-f`:

```
jtc -f myjsonfile.json
```

btw, to *convert it back* to one-liner again: `jtc -fr myjsonfile.json`

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) - shell cli tool for JSON operations

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing the repository.

Comment: you're very welcome, hopefully you will like the tool!

Answer (score -1):

if you can identify a character sequence that ends a line (e.g. a curly bracket followed by a semicolon) you can use sed for it

```
$ sed 's/};/\n/g' <<< "my};test};string"
my
test
string
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I didn't know where a line ends. The above answer works fine.